# Unable to run local collection on docker image

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, postman, newman

I’m fairly new with docker, however I came across various blogs on how to run local collections on docker, but I still get an error, any help would be appreciate. I have the following that I would like to mount on the newman image

docker run -v /C:/Users/name.surname/collection:/etc/postman -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 \run “https:/www.getpostman.com/collections/xxxxx” --environment=“Test.postman_environment.json” ----ssl-client-cert test.cer --ssl-client-key test.key --insecure --testReportFile=“newman-report.xml”

and the error I get is as follows docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /etc/postman.

unfortunately I don't seem to understand this error to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The format for volume to mount a bind is `-v <source>:<destination>:<mode>` mode can be optional and doesnt have to be passed. The issue is in your source, you pass in a colon which is a separator of the fields in the volume attributes.

`-v /C<:>/Users/msingathi.majola/collection<:>/etc/postman`

I have wrapped your colons in `< >` just to highlight them but as you see it will read it as

```
src = /C
dest= /Users/msingathi.majola/collection
mode= /etc/postman
```

Which is why you get the error `invalid mode: /etc/postman`. You should instead specify the volume parameters explicitly using `--mount`.

Comment: hi Chris, thanks for the response, I just tried it this way now and still getting an error 'docker run -v /c/Users/msingathi.majola/collection /etc/postman -t postman/newman_ubuntu1404 \run “https:/www.getpostman.com/collections/xxxxx” --environment=“Test.postman_environment.json” ----ssl-client-cert test.cer --ssl-client-key test.key --insecure --testReportFile=“newman-report.xml”'' also the --mount command throws an error. Please advise.

Comment: you dont show how you have used mount. the syntax would be `--mount type=bind, src=<your source>, dst=<your dest>` that should replace your volume part. It will remove any issues in your source or dest having a colon in them as you pass the source and dest as seperate keys, rather than passing a single string which volume would parse and split by colon

Comment: Ok apologies for not being detailed enough, just wrapping my head around this. I used the following format 'docker run -v --mount type=bind, src=C/Users/msingathi.majola/collection, dst=/etc/newman -t postman/newman run "https:/www.getpostman.com/collections/xxx" -- --environment="Test.postman_environment.json" --ssl-client-cert test.cer --ssl-client-key test.key --insecure --testReportFile="newman-report.xml"' and I get an invalid reference format

Comment: you dont pass the -v and --mount, mount replaces the need to pass -v. And dont have any spaces between the key value params. Also it looks like your using windows, are you sure the format/syntax of your path is correct?

Comment: Yeah that's my path in my local machine